# How to get an IP address from Socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to get an ip address that is bound to receiveSock. How can i get it.

**Ques 1:**

```
ipEndReceive = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, receivePort);
receiveSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                        , SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

receiveSock.Bind(ipEndReceive);
```

When code reaches Bind function. An error occurs

> Invalid Argument, Error Code: 10022,
>   Message : An invalid argument was
>   supplied

**Ques 2:**

```
ipEndReceive = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), receivePort);
receiveSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                        , SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);                   
receiveSock.Bind(ipEndReceive);

ErrorLog.WritetoErrorlog("\nRemote IP Address : " + ((IPEndPoint)receiveSock.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()
```

When I tries with this Ip. It shows me the same error as above

Comment: @tanascius: thanks for making me realize my mistake. I formatted it now.

Comment: thx, it is really easier to read and answer well formatted questions ^^

Answer (score 1):

First, it looks like it's the local end point you want. Secondly when you specify `IPAddress.Any` (`0.0.0.0`) you explicitly state that the `Socket` is to be bound to no particular interface. Each IP adress matches exactly one interface.

```
var s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
s.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, somePort));
Trace.WriteLine(s.LocalEndPoint); // should be what you're looking for
```

The socket is bound and will be used for receiving connections. It doesn't have a `RemoteEndPoint`. This should be abundantly clear becuase the `Accept` method returns a new `Socket` object that represents the connection between two end points (local/remote).

Note: that this is an IPv4 socket (`AddressFamily.InterNetwork`) so don't try and bind it to anything else.

Check out the docs on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx), you can learn more about typical Winsock programming (as the Socket class is just a Winsock wrapper) there.

Comment: Thx for explanation. Could u put some light on your first three lines. I m not sure what you are trying to explain. **Socket is to be bound to no particular interface** What does `interface` represents here

Comment: interface referes to a specific component in the network stack. your computer can be connected to the internet (or local network) in many ways. you can have several connections (wired and wireless). each active interface represents such a connection and has a distinct IP address. When you type `netsh interface ipv4 show addresses` you get a list of all currently installed network interfaces. One such interface is the loopback interface which has the static IP address `127.0.0.1`. When I say no particular interface, I mean that a connection may be made on any interface.

Comment: If you computer is a gateway or firewall, you can restrict access from either side of the network, by allowing connections only on specific interfaces. I believe this relates more to network segementation than your original question though.