# How to get an ip address from an IPEndPoint obtained in a socket

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming

```
 ipEndReceive = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), receivePort);
 receiveSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream
                          , ProtocolType.Tcp);

 ErrorLog.WritetoErrorlog("Trying to Bind IP Address Stored in  Variable : "
                          +ipEndReceive.Address.ToString()
                          +"\n Port No :"+ipEndReceive.Port.ToString(), logPath);

 receiveSock.Bind(ipEndReceive);


 ErrorLog.WritetoErrorlog("\nRemote IP Address : " 
                    + ((IPEndPoint)receiveSock.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString()
                    + "\n Local IP:" 
                    + ((IPEndPoint)receiveSock.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString()
                    , logPath);
```

Here `receiveSock.RemoteEndPoint` returns me an instance of `EndPoint` rather than `IPEndPoint` due to which i m not able to get the remote ip address from where request has been received. 
Do we have any way to get it from this socket.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an IP address from Socket](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138885/how-to-get-an-ip-address-from-socket)

Comment: @ho1: I think this is closely related to the previous question i asked. But here question is bit different. Here I am pointing out at getting IP address from **EndPoint**

Comment: EndPoint is an abstract class.  I don't get the problem, does the cast fail?

Comment: Since they are so closely related and posted so soon after each other I think it would be better to edit the original question with the new information rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @Hans: After reading the line where I m casting. It directly goes to finally block skipping all the lines written between. No exception is being thrown. I m not getting what the exact reason is as i cannot test this application at my end. And I have only server class and have to check everything and make changes in server class only.

Answer (score 0):

Socket RemoteEndpoint will be set after socket is connected.

That means that logging RemoteEndpoint after bind is not correct.

> The RemoteEndPoint is set after a call to either Accept or Connect. If you try to access this property earlier, RemoteEndPoint will throw a SocketException. If you receive a SocketException, use the SocketException::ErrorCode property to obtain the specific error code. After you have obtained this code, refer to the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in the MSDN library for a detailed description of the error."

(from MSDN)